# Windows recursive unzipping 7zip .zip batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, cmd, 7zip

I have a hugue zip (1.5Gb) on my FAT-32 29Gb USB which contains an awfully messy mix of zip and folders.

Unfortunately I must use Windows to do it. So I tried to create a batch that would recursively unzip all files then delete the archives.

Somehow it isn't working exactly as I want ( not all zip are deleted/unzipped ). What is wrong with my code ?

```
@FOR /R %%a IN (*.zip) DO @(
    @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%a" -o"%%~dpna" -aoa
    @DEL /F /S /Q "%%a"
)
```

EDIT : The batch itselfs works just fine the issue is caused by very long path name ( 250+ characters ). I found a way around that with... cut paste unzip cut paste ... . For the people that will need an answer and can't do that is there a clean way around that ?

Comment: is there a pattern in the files that work and that don't?

Comment: seems the batch itself is fine when I used the folder search bar of windows i have strange things like D:\DOCUME~1 etc I think it might be because stuffs like 8.3, i'm looking into it atm